# How do I add a project?

Tags: 8

How do I add a Drupal 8 project (e.g. the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module) to my site?

Comment: Hey :) Since you deleted another one of your other questions, I'll abuse this one a bit. Can I get you to discuss your "content type on front page"-question in [chat]? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps  to install from UI

Go to Manage >> Extend

[image]

Click on Install new module.

[image]

Install From URL or upload a module archive to install.

[image]

**Second Method:**

Just download module archive zip and extract to

yoursite >> modules

You can place downloaded and custom modules in modules directory.

Here in the given example installation directory is d8.

[image]

That's it. go to your module list. you can find your downloaded module there.

Comment: Thanks i used this link: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/panels-8.x-3.0-alpha2.tar.gz and pressed install but it didnt show up in my extend page what did i do wrong?

Comment: @Stefan Seems d8 bug. But try the second method which I've mentioned in my answer. That definitely works.

Comment: @Stefan Great!.. you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 5):

The third solution would be:

1- Install drush : https://www.drupal.org/node/1791676

2- Move to the local home directory of your drupal website inside the Command Prompt / Terminal (according to your OS type)

3- Type this command in the Command Prompt / Terminal (according to your OS type):

`drush en panels -y`

Comment: Great Eshan, Infact I was about to add drush method to my answer. Due to lack of time I couldn't do it. :)

Comment: It's OK. Both of us are trying to help!